# How to ensure sequential execution of windows batch files (.bat)

Tags: windows, batch-file

My windows batch file `xs33.bat` contains two commands:

```
xs33a.bat
xs33b.bat
```

The first one edits a file. The 2nd uses it as input in a calculation.

What I'm finding is the calculation `xs33b.bat` is running before the file is edited, i.e. before `xs33a.bat` has finished executing.

If I enter the same commands by hand one after another, there is enough time for `xs33a.bat` to complete, before running `xs33b.bat` and I get the correct answer.  However, running both in a batch file gives the wrong answer.

What can I do to ensure that `xs33a.bat` finishes before running `xs33b.bat`.

I've tried a number of things without success:  adding `call`;  and putting both lines on the same line joined by one or two ampersands; inserting `pause` between the two lines, without success.

Comment: Please take the [tour], read [Ask] and [MCVE].  What launches these batch files when you're not running them manually?  Is it a script?

Comment: There is no way xs33b.bat is running at all!  Once xs33a.bat is executed control passes to that batch file and never returns to xs33.bat.  You have to use CALL in front of each batch file.  Batch files are sequential processing.  It will not execute the next line until the previous command has completed.

Comment: "Squashman 23" seems to know it with great certainty, but what he writes is not what my computer does.  As stated in the original questions, I still find that still using Call, the xs33b.bat is running and producing (wrong) results before xs33a.bat is complete.   If xs33a.bat were complete xs33b.bat would produce the right result.

Answer (score 1):

you could try running the 2nd one from the first one, after the calculation is done.

Answer (score 1):

You say that you have tried using `Call`.

As you haven't provided an example of doing so, did you try it just `Call`ing `xs33a.bat`. Control should return to `xs33.bat` after execution of `xs33a.bat`?

Like this:

```bat
@Call "xs33a.bat"
@"xs33b.bat"
```

Comment: I tried it exactly as stated, and it worked perfectly!  Still I'd appreciate  more info to understand better.  What does the @ at the beginning of the command line do?  Why quote the batch file name?  What is the difference between using "Call" and not using Call?   Where can I find info on this?

Comment: Looking further I found that @ makes the command run in  a less verbose manner.  Thus it is possible that running xs33a.bat less verbosely, made it execute faster, so it could complete its work, before xs33b.bat used the file, but I think I still don't have the answer to "how can I GUARANTEE that execution of commands in a batch file will be sequential and not simultaneous".  This seems to me like a simple enough question, though unfortunately that does not necessarily mean it has a simple answer.